# How to conditionally display HTML based on the page URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few different web pages -

```
www.foo.com/index.html
www.foo.com/dog.html
www.foo.com/cat.html
```

Assume the pages are very similar, except for an image and some text in the middle of the page that's unique to that page.

I have an external script that dynamically creates the HTML for each page using templates and substituting in various variables and configurations. I'm trying to figure out how to display a certain piece of HTML only for a certain page (e.g. cat.html)

In psuedo-code, this is what I'd like to do -

```
  <style>
    function isCatPage() {
      if page.url.contains("cat.html")
        return true;
      else
        return false;
      end
    }
  </style>

  if isCatPage {
  <bold>This text only appears on cat.html</bold>
  }

  <p> This is random dynamically generated HTML</p>
</body>
```

Using basic javascript to show `<bold>` on an specific HTML page.

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: for the SEO reasons, I would do this server side and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

I would use jquery and do something like the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // only run this when the page finishes loading
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // if cat.html exists in the url
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('cat.html') > -1) {
            // select the p by its id and hide it or - 
            $('#conditional').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        else {
            // show it
            $('#conditional').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
</script>

<p id='conditional'>This text only appears on cat.html</p>
<p>This is random dynamically generated HTML</p>
```

Comment: Let me add, that it isn't safe to let the client decide what to show. Especially if it's anything that they shouldn't be able to see, e.g. insufficient right, etc

Comment: sur @Ted it's not sur but I found it inteligent where he put an id='conditional', and this separate the part javascript(code) and part HTML.  so +1

Answer (score 1):

Get the current url, and split it

```
var url_parts = location.href.split(/\//g);
var page = url_parts[url_parts.length-1];
```

`page` should contain the current page (eg `cat.html`)

Although, I'd really suggest you use a server for this kind of stuff